# How to properly start a script generated by gradle using upstart?

Tags: java, linux, bash, gradle, upstart

I'm trying to deploy an Java app onto VPS. I'm using Gradle build system with 'application' plugin. I want the app to start up with the server.

During deployment process I run `./gradlew install` to prepare run scripts. When ran directly, they work properly.

I used http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2014/02/ubuntu-upstart-job-with-java-jar.html as a base for upstart configuration:

```
description "the test server"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect fork

script
   cd /opt/testserver/
   exec ./build/install/testserver/bin/testserver
end script
```

But the PID reported by upstart after running `start testserver` is different then the one found using `ps`. My guess is that the reason for that is the last line of generated script:

`exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" mypackage.TestServer"$@"`

As a result Upstart is not able to stop the app. Is there a way to make upstart see the right PID?

Comment: Can you paste the full contents of the testserver script (exec'd by the Upstart job)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there is no forking going on here, so you should try removing the `expect fork` bit.

Comment: You are right. "exec" replaces the current process so there is no forking involved.